# Pascal - How do i return values based on one condition?

Tags: arrays, function, enums, pascal

I want to display all of the customers who have purchased an item within a specific day, would this be done by using the customers array with if/else statements or using the day enum? Any help or an example would be great, thank you!

```
type
day = (monday, tuesday);

Tcustomer = record
    name:String;
    itemPurchased:string;
    dayPurchased: Tday;
end;

TCustomers = array of Tcustomer;

function readDay(prompt:string): day;
var
    selection:Integer;
begin
    writeln('1. Monday');
    writeln('2. Tuesday');

    selection := ReadIntegerRange('Select day purcased (1 - 3): ', 1, 
    3);
    result := day(selection-1);
end;

function readCustomers(prompt:string):TCustomers;
var
    numOfCustomers:integer;
    i:integer;
begin
    numOfCustomers := ReadInteger('Enter number of customers: ');
    setLength(result, numOfCustomers);

    for i := 0 to high(result)do
    begin
        result[i].name := ReadString('Customer name: ');
        result[i].itemPurchased := ReadString('Item Purchased: ');
        result[i].dayPurchased := readDay(prompt);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: *...using the customers array with if/else statements or using the day enum*. I guess the answer is both? Not sure why you think these are alternatives of each other. You have to check each customer entry for the desired enum value.

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

define `Customers` variable
get customers array into it
create procedure with `specific_day` argument
inside this procedure make a loop and check all array elements with `if-`operator that compares `dayPurchased` field with `specific_day`